# Missing vcruntime140.dll for wxMEdit 3.1 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

While upgrading my wxMEdit from 3.0 to 3.1, it complaint about missing vcruntime140.dll. Installed 64-bit version still not work. Some other answers said needs to reboot. Not working still.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. Go to the following link:

[Microsoft VCRUNTIME](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Follow the instruction and you will find 32-bit x86 and 64-bit x86_64 versions. Click on x86 32-bit version. Install it. No need to reboot system.

EDIT: This was my working experience from not-working. If incorrect or incomplete, please comment. Thanks!